# Understanding Permissions with ProFTPD (Especially Group Write)

Tags: ftp, proftpd, umask

I have proftpd running under user proftpd. I have a new virtual server in ProFTPD called "example.com" pointing to `/var/www/example.com`. I have chowned the `/var/www/example.com` folder with user "example_com" and group "www-data". I have set the directory as SGID (2775). This permits the FTP user "example_com" to login and upload files and folders, while permitting the Apache process user "www-data" to run the website and read/write to files.

In my `proftpd.conf`, I have set umask like so:

```
Umask 2664 2775
```

My trouble is this. When "example_com" creates a new file, it's setting it as 2644 instead of 2664. And when creating a new directory, it's setting it as 2755 instead of 2775. In both cases, it's missing the "group-writable" permission.

How do I turn on Group Write in ProFTPD globally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs, you cannot set the SGID bit in the umask directive; it says: "Any arguments supplied must be an octal number, in the format 0xxx."

http://proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_Umask.html

As joschi alludes to, what you really want is "Umask 0002" - a umask is bitwise to the object, not an absolute CHMOD setting. You only need to specify it once (not "umask 0002 0002") as the first will apply to all.

Comment: I had to use `Umask 002 002` make it work with both files and directories.

Answer (score 2):

This is nothing specific to ProFTPd, it's standard POSIX permissions "math".

You are mixing up the actual permissions on a file and the umask. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask for an introduction.